# Regex expression - match specific characters (multiple times) and ignore comments

Tags: c#, regex

I'm not an expert on regex and need some help to set up one.

I'm using Powershell and its [regex] type, which is a [C# class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8), the final objective is to read a toml file (sample data at the bottom, or use this [link to regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fOAPs9/1)), in which I need to:

- match some values (values between "__")
- ignore comments.  (a comment starts with "#")

To match the values and put them in a capture group the following regex works:

```
match the template value (values between "__" ):
__(?<tokenName>[\w\.]+)__
```

I also want to ignore the commented lines, and I came up with this:

```
Ignore lines that start with a comment (even if "#" is preceded by spaces or tabs):
^(?!\s*\t*#).*
```

The problem starts when I put them together

```
^(?!\s*\t*#).*__(?<tokenName>[\w\.]+)__
```

this expression has the following problems:

1. up to one match per line, the last one (ie: in the line with "Prop5 = ..." I get one match instead of two)
2. Comments at the end of a line are not considered (ie: line with "Prop4 = ..." has two matches instead of one)

I've also tried to

```
add this at the end of the expression, it should stop the match on the first occurrence of the character
[^#]

add this at the beginning, which should check if the matched string has the given char before it and exclude it
(?<!^#)
```

This is a sample of my data

```
#templateFile
[Agent]
    Prop1 = "__Data.Agent.Prop1__"
    Prop2 = [__Data.Agent.Prop2__]
    #I'm a comment
    #Prop3 = "__NotUsed__"
    Prop4 = [__Data.Agent.Prop4__] #sample usage comment __Data.Agent.xxx__
    Prop5 = ["__Data.Agent.Prop5a__","__Data.Agent.Prop5b__"]
```

I think the easier solution will be to match the given string, only if there is no "#" before it on the same line.
Is it possible?

**EDIT:**

The first expression proposed by @the-fourth-bird works perfectly, it just needs the multiline modifier to be specified.
The final (runnable) result looks like this in PowerShell.

```
[regex]$reg = "(?m)(?<!^.*#.*)__(?<tokenName>[\w.]+)__"

$text = '
#templateFile
[Agent]
    Prop1 = "__Data.Agent.Prop1__"
    Prop2 = [__Data.Agent.Prop2__]
    Prop5 = ["__Data.Agent.Prop5a__","__Data.Agent.Prop5b__"]
    #a comment
    #Prop3 = "__Data.Agent.Prop3__"
    Prop4 = [__Data.Agent.Prop4__] #sample usage comment __Data.Agent.xxx__
'

$reg.Matches($text) | Format-Table
#This returns
Groups         Success Name Captures Index Length Value
------         ------- ---- -------- ----- ------ -----
{0, tokenName}    True 0    {0}         31     20 __Data.Agent.Prop1__
{0, tokenName}    True 0    {0}         62     20 __Data.Agent.Prop2__
{0, tokenName}    True 0    {0}         94     21 __Data.Agent.Prop5a__
{0, tokenName}    True 0    {0}        118     21 __Data.Agent.Prop5b__
{0, tokenName}    True 0    {0}        194     20 __Data.Agent.Prop4__
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could make use of [infinite repetition](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind_width) to check if what precedes does not contain a `#` to also account for the comment in Prop4

```
(?<!^.*#.*)__(?<tokenName>[\w.]+)__
```

[.Net regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5e.*%23.*%29__%28%3f%3ctokenName%3e%5b%5cw.%5d%2b%29__&i=%23templateFile%0d%0a%5bAgent%5d%0d%0a++++Prop1+%3d+%22__Data.Agent.Prop1__%22%0d%0a++++Prop2+%3d+%5b__Data.Agent.Prop2__%5d%0d%0a++++%23I%27m+a+comment%0d%0a++++%23Prop3+%3d+%22__NotUsed__%22%0d%0a++++Prop4+%3d+%5b__Data.Agent.Prop4__%5d+%23sample+usage+comment+__Data.Agent.xxx__%0d%0a++++Prop5+%3d+%5b%22__Data.Agent.Prop5a__%22%2c%22__Data.Agent.Prop5b__%22%5d&o=m)

If Prop4 should have 2 matches, you might use:

```
(?<!^[ \t]*#.*)__(?<tokenName>[\w.]+)__
```

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5e%5b+%5ct%5d*%23.*%29__%28%3f%3ctokenName%3e%5b%5cw.%5d%2b%29__&i=%23templateFile%0d%0a%5bAgent%5d%0d%0a++++Prop1+%3d+%22__Data.Agent.Prop1__%22%0d%0a++++Prop2+%3d+%5b__Data.Agent.Prop2__%5d%0d%0a++++%23I%27m+a+comment%0d%0a++++%23Prop3+%3d+%22__NotUsed__%22%0d%0a++++Prop4+%3d+%5b__Data.Agent.Prop4__%5d+%23sample+usage+comment+__Data.Agent.xxx__%0d%0a++++Prop5+%3d+%5b%22__Data.Agent.Prop5a__%22%2c%22__Data.Agent.Prop5b__%22%5d&o=m)

Both expressions needs the multiline modifier to work properly.
it can be specified inline by adding (?m) at the beginning. (or by specifying it in a constructor that supports it)

```
(?m)(?<!^.*#.*)__(?<tokenName>[\w.]+)__
```